# How to find the optimal situation using this Seating Arragement, pencils scenario

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I like to think of this scenario as similar to a seating arrangement with extra steps.
In this scenario, we have pencil packs and desks. Each desk has a maximum number of pencils it can hold, and each pack of pencils has a pre-defined set of pencils.
Some pencils cannot be mixed with one another while others can and some share preference on what desk those pencils can be placed on.
All pencils must be placed.

So how do I find the most optimal solution to make sure some pencils are never mixed and some are minimally mixed.

Here are some arrays I have to work with.

This is the desk's array, the number inside corresponds to the maximum pencils it can hold * 4. Each number is a separate section of the desk and may contain any pencil.

```
local Desks = {
    {"Desk1",2,{}},
    {"Desk2",7,{}},
    {"Desk3",4,{}},
    {"Desk4",2,{}},
    {"Desk5",5,{}},
    {"Desk6",16,{}},
    {"Desk7",3,{}},
    {"Desk8",2,{}},
    {"Desk9",8,{}},
    {"Desk10",6,{}},
    {"Desk11",6,{}}
  };
```

The number inside defines how many pencils are in a pack that needs to be spread out.

```
local PencilsInPacks = {
  {"AnnoyingPencils",10,{"PencilHate","PencilHate2"},{}},
  {"Pencil1",10,{},{}},
  {"Pencil2",40,{},{}},
  {"Pencil3",40,{},{}},
  {"Pencil4",40,{},{}},
  {"PencilHate",40,{"AnnoyingPencils"},{"PencilHate2"}},
  {"PencilHate2",30,{"AnnoyingPencils"},{"PencilHate"}}
}
```

In this example, The annoying pencil cannot be placed on a desk with PencilHate or PencilHate2. PencilHate & Hate2 do not like to be placed together but it's okay if they are, while not ideal.

I ask the question how do I properly get the most optimal solution, what tools should I use?
I have run into any problems with this, it takes me a rather long time to organize the most optimal solution by hand and even then I see room for improvement.
The output should hopefully store what pencil Pack names are placed at each desk.

This is the first question I've ever made on a coding forum and hope I'm not asking too much.

Comment: Can you share the expected solution for your example? Also, do all pencils from the same pack have to be placed on the same desk, or can they split up to several desks?

Comment: Yes, I should have originally included an expected outcome. 
The pencils could be split any amount of desks.

The output should be something like this spread.
[link](https://prnt.sc/aCMXJU3FYSix)